# session not working asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I got a problem this session : 
it's not working

```
    protected bool ValidateForm()
{
    if (username.Text == "")
    {
        Err.Text = "please enter username" + "<br/>";
        return false;
    }
    if (password.Text == "")
    {
        Err.Text = "please enter password" + "<br/>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateForm())
    {
        SqlDataReader rd1 = Connection.Query("select count(id) as count from sarcadmintable where username ='" + username.Text+"'",true);
        if(rd1.Read())
        {
            if (rd1["count"].ToString() == "0") Err.Text = "please check your username" + "<br/>";
            else
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = Connection.Query("select * from sarcadmintable where username ='" + username.Text + "'", true);
                if (rd.Read())
                {
                    if (rd["password"].ToString() != password.Text)
                        Err.Text = "password is not correct" + "<br/>";
                    else
                    {
                        Session["id"] = rd["user_id"].ToString();
                        Session["prev"] = rd["prev"].ToString();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Return"].ToString()))
                            Response.Redirect(Encryption.Decypt_URL(Request.QueryString["Return"]));
                        else
                            Response.Redirect("Main/Default.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

thats the code for login its work fine
... in the header of the master.site I put this code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["user_id"] == null || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "" || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "0") Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?Return=" + Encryption.Encypt_URL(Request.Url + ""));
            SqlDataReader rd = Connection.Query("select firstname + ' ' + lastname as name from sarcuser where id=" + int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString()), true);
            if (rd.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = rd["name"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the web.config :

```
<!--<sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="525600" mode="InProc" stateNetworkTimeout="525600"/>-->  
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="he-IL"/>
    </system.web>
```

I make the session as a comment so I take the default for session

but its not working ... every time I press login with true username and password ... its redirect me to the login page ... and take the session as empty string

but the login code is fine and recover the right value ... any help ?

Comment: Session issues aside, you have a few SQL Injection vulnerabilities in the code; consider parameterizing the SQL command at the very least. As to the Session issue, what are you using for authentication? The fact that you are being redirected to the login page after logging in with correct credentials indicates an incorrect authentication process

Comment: I miss understand you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code in Page_Load

```
if (Session["user_id"] == null || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "" || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "0") Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?Return=" + Encryption.Encypt_URL(Request.Url + ""));
```

you are checking for user_id (Session["user_id"]) while you are storing with key id (Session["id"] = ....) in login button click handler

**Edit: The above solution added**

---

### **Previously provided out of context answer**, left below as I think it may be useful for someone to know about this

The code that you are writing in the Page_Load event handler of master page, put that code in PreRender event handler and your label will be updated properly.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["user_id"] == null || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "" || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "0")
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?Return=" + Encryption.Encypt_URL(Request.Url + ""));

            SqlDataReader rd = Connection.Query("select firstname + ' ' + lastname as name from sarcuser where id=" + int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString()), true);
            if (rd.Read())
            {
                label1.Text = rd["name"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Now why this is happening?**

This is happening because the Page_Load of the master page is called before the button_Click of the content page (Refer: [Sequence that events are raised for Pages, UserControls, MasterPages and HttpModules](http://forums.asp.net/t/1191194.aspx?FAQ%20Sequence%20that%20events%20are%20raised%20for%20Pages%20UserControls%20MasterPages%20and%20HttpModules). So the execution happens as follows:

1. Your browser request the page (login.aspx)
2. Login class is instantiated
3. `OnPreInit` of Login page is invoked (which specifies the master page)
4. Master page is instantiated
5. Login.`Page_Load` is executed
6. Master.`Page_Load` is executed
7. Your browser is requested to redirect to login.aspx
8. Execution terminates (why? because `Response.Redirect` causes current thread to terminate. If you want to prevent this abnormal termination and execute the complete page, pass 'false' as second parameter to `Response.Redirect(url, false)`

So, as you can see above, your button_click is never executed.

**How to make user login**

There are multiple options:

- Do not use the same master page for the login page.
- On the master page, check if current page is login.aspx, ignore the checking of login
- Create a master page that specify the UI design and functionality that is same across public and authenticated access (call this master1.master). Create another master page (master2.master) which specify the check for authenticated user and functionality specific to authenticated user. Now login page will user master1.master as the master page and authenticated pages will user master2.master as master page. (somewhat same as first point, but the UI design is now placed in one master page only)

*Any other that developers out there could suggest*

**Note:** As suggested above, checking for authenticated user in PreRender is not recommended at all (that was just to update the label) as it may cause some code to be executed which should be prevented in one case or the other.

Comment: I already did what you say ... I have to master page one for the login only and other for the webapplication ... but still not working and I add the code you did to header its throw me an error

Comment: which header? I provided the code to be added in OnPreRender.... also, if you have separate master page for login, do not check user's session in that page.

Comment: I got masterpage2.site its just for login and no check for session .. and masterpage1.site its for the website and in controls called header ... I check for session ... but it's also redirect me to the login page ... and I tried to print the session["user_id"] in login.aspx its work fine and gave me the right value

Comment: do you have this control (called header) on masterpage2.site as well?

Comment: no its just on masterpage1.site that holding the whole website

Comment: check the first 3 lines of my answer now

Comment: still don't get it ... what the wrong with the code ??? 
I tried to user onpreload it gave me that error : 
Controls_Header.OnPreRender(System.EventArgs)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(System.Ev

Comment: the modifier will be protected instead of public (my bad)

Comment: change "user_id" in ====>>>> "if (Session["user_id"] == null || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "" || Session["user_id"].ToString() == "0")".......... to ===> "id" (as you are using "id" in login_click)

Comment: Ooh .. that is the tax of working for 16 hour ... stupid fault 
(feeling shame) ... thanks Manish Dalal

Comment: its ok @SamySamour, sometimes we unknowingly exaggerate a simple problem. As you can see from my previous reply, I was also prejudiced regarding the problem and provided that long answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any actual user.authenticate() in your code. Is your page managed by another layer of authentication somewhere? For eg. I go to an open page, enter my credentials, you check my credentials, redirect me to a page that authenticates me and then boom I am back at login page. Also you might consider moving your authentication to the page_init unless you want to do it on every postback. I think you need to post a bit more here.

Comment: see my edit I posted all the code of the login and it's work fine and with true value but the problem is in session